# PIC16F877A stops working when I remove the PICkit 3

Tags: pickit, pic16f877a

I've made codes of different sequences of lights but somehow this one does not work when I remove the PICkit 3, as long as the PICkit is on the circuit works.

I am supplying my circuit with a 5V-3A power supply and I am using a PIC16F877A

When I press a button situated in RC0, the following sequence of lights happens:

```
DEFINE OSC 4

TRISC=%00000001
TRISD=%00000000

START:

PORTC=0
PORTD=0

IF PORTC.0=1 THEN

PORTD=%11111111
PAUSE 4000
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 500

PORTD=%11111111
PAUSE 500
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 500 

PORTD=%11111111
PAUSE 500
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 500 

PORTD=%11111111
PAUSE 500
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 500 

PORTD=%11111111
PAUSE 500
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 500 

PORTD=%00000011
PAUSE 500
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 500

PORTD=%00001100
PAUSE 500
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 500

PORTD=%00110000
PAUSE 500
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 500

PORTD=%11000000
PAUSE 500
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 500

PORTD=%01010101
PAUSE 500
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 500

PORTD=%01010101
PAUSE 500
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 500

PORTD=%00110011
PAUSE 500
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 500

PORTD=%00110011
PAUSE 500
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 500

PORTD=%00110011
PAUSE 500
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 500

PORTD=%11000111
PAUSE 500
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 500

PORTD=%01010101
PAUSE 100
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 100

PORTD=%01010101
PAUSE 100
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 100

PORTD=%01010101
PAUSE 100
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 100

PORTD=%01010101
PAUSE 100
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 100

PORTD=%01010101
PAUSE 100
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 100

PORTD=%01010101
PAUSE 100
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 100

PORTD=%01010101 
PAUSE 100
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 100

PORTD=%01010101
PAUSE 100
PORTD=%00000000
PAUSE 100

ENDIF 
GOTO START
END
```

Here is the schematic of the circuit:

[image]

I have already uploaded other sequences into the PIC and they work just fine with the external power supply, I am not really sure why this one does not work without the PICkit 3

Comment: Are you 100% sure that R2 is pulling MCLR high? That has bitten me several times.

Comment: Yes, it is, I already even checked with my multimeter the resistor and it is definitely connected to +5V and it resets the program whenever I press the PB1

Comment: I didn't see any power supply in your circuit.